# C# iTextSharp PDFReader Reads From Beginning of PDF Always

Tags: c#, itext, pdf-reader

I am using iTextSharp PDFReader to read a pdf file that has 18 pages but every time I increment the page number, it starts from the beginning of the pdf instead of reading just that particular page.  If I set "x" to the pdfReader.NumberOfPages value, it only reads the last page.  I would like to read each page individually and add the data to my list of string s.  I am also going through a folder, reading each pdf file, but I am testing with just one at first.

```
List<string> s = new List<string>();
while (z < filePaths.Count())
{
    PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(filePaths[z]); 
    ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
    for (int x = 1; x <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; x++)
    {
        string currentText = "";                                
        currentText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, x, strategy);                        
        s.Add(currentText);
    }
    z++;
    pdfReader.Close();
}
```

Comment: does it always read the first page only, except for the last page, or does it read everything from first to xth page each? the underlying workhorse method `ProcessContent<E>(int pageNumber, E renderListener)` clearly should do what you intend... which version of ITextSharp do you use?

Comment: using 5.5.10.0, it always starts at the first page and reads until the xth page

Comment: just to make sure... do you expect `s` to contain all pages of all files, one page worth of text per list item, when the outer loop is finished?

Comment: Yes, I am wanting to read the pdf page by page and insert each page of text as a list item.

Answer (score 5):

All previous answers are pretty close, i.e. you were correctly blaming it on some kind of state issue.

The only part that was missing is that it is the `strategy` variable that remembers its state. After calling `GetTextFromPage`, your strategy object does not flush its existing contents.

So the trick is to instantiate your `strategy` inside the loop:

```
for (int x = 1; x <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; x++)
{
    ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
    string currentText = "";                                
    currentText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, x, strategy);                        
    s.Add(currentText);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Got it to work by removing the strategy from this line `PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, x, strategy)`

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> filePaths = new List<string>();
            filePaths.Add("C:\\temp\\pe\\ACN-ONFBG-010-R-EN-ONT (1364).pdf");
            filePaths.Add("C:\\temp\\pe\\ACN-ONFBG-010-R-UN-NOR (1364).pdf");
            filePaths.Add("C:\\temp\\pe\\ACN-ONFBG-010-R-UN-SOU (1364).pdf");
            List<string> results = doit(filePaths);
            string stall = "stall";
        }


        private static List<string> doit(List<string> filePaths)
        {
            List<string> s = new List<string>();
            int z = 0;
            while (z < filePaths.Count())
            {
                PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(filePaths[z]);
                ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
                for (int x = 1; x <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; x++)
                {
                    string currentText = "";
                    currentText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, x);
                    s.Add(currentText);
                }
                z++;
                pdfReader.Close();
            }
            return s;
        }
```

Comment: that invokes the default, `LocationTextExtractionStrategy`, instead of `SimpleTextExtractionStrategy`. Obviously, the latter does not handle page boundaries properly - no idea if by definition, or because of a bug.

Comment: It makes it work regardless. It went from not-working, to working and that's the only change I made to make it work. At this point, I'd lean towards a bug. Bruno is often on here answering iText related question, hopefully he'll see this one and chip in.

Comment: that's why I upvoted, although the discussion below my answer led to the same conclusion :) let's hope someone from iText reads this, they might explain, or fix.

Comment: Funny enough... it looks like whenever a third parameter is passed, it stops working. I just tried it again by setting `strategy` to `LocationTextExtractionStrategy` and I'm back to the original behavior posted by the op.

Comment: This will do the trick in this instance, because iText will create a strategy internally for each page individually (i.e. per `GetTextFromPage` call). See http://stackoverflow.com/a/41038493/2065017

Answer (score 0):

I suspect a reader state issue. Try opening the PdfReader once before the loop to get the page count. Store the page count in a variable. Use that variable as the upper bound for the loop. Then in the loop, instantiate a new PdfReader for every page, dispose it after each iteration.

**EDIT**: It turned out that the text extraction strategy is the culprit. It retains state somehow. Always instantiate a new `SimpleTextExtractionStrategy` before calling `GetTextFromPage`, or omit the `strategy` parameter - then a new instance of the default implementation of `ITextExtractionStrategy` will be created internally.

Comment: I tried the following and still got the same result as above:  for (int x = 1; x <= count; x++)
                    {
                        PdfReader newReader = new PdfReader(filePaths[z]);
                        string currentText = "";                                
                        currentText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(newReader, x, strategy);                        
                        s.Add(currentText);
                        newReader.Dispose();
                    }

Comment: weird. we should make sure that the page dictionary of that PDF isn't broken ... can you try with any other PDF file? and your remark that it works when you set `x` to the number of pages: what happens, if you set it to, let's say, 7?

Comment: I could just use another list of strings and grab the last index of "s", but I am afraid it may not contain all the data from the pdf since string lengths are limited and I am not sure of how many pages may be in any one of these pdfs

Comment: Let me clarify, if I set x to 18, the number of pages in this pdf, it only reads the 18th page, not the entire pdf.  If I set it to 7, it reads the 7th page and then on the next loop it reads the 7th and 8th pages, and so on...

Comment: hard to believe. how do you know? debugger, or output? flaw in output code? if not, [documentation](http://developers.itextpdf.com/reference/com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor) would support that your approach is correct and you have a broken PDF or found a bug.

Comment: I am debugging and looking at the currentText variable, I tried a different pdf and still the same issue

Comment: then it has to be a reader state issue, otherwise how could it possibly fetch the first-to-fetch correctly, if it is the 18 or the 7? also, there is no overload of that function which would take a from...to page number. try omitting the extraction strategy argument, does that help?

Comment: That made it work.  I had tried this earlier but was getting the same result, I think calling the PDFReader and disposing it each time I read a page fixed the issue